# Inequality for some expression $B$

Tags: inequality

Suppose we have some expression say $B$ is such that $$B \leq -\alpha \|x\| + \frac{\alpha^{2}}{2}\left(\kappa + \frac{1}{1 - \alpha}\right).$$ Now take $$\alpha = \min\left\{\frac{\|x\|}{\kappa + 2}, \frac{1}{\kappa + 2}\right\} \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$ From this point how can I get $$B \leq -\min\left\{\frac{\|x\|^{2}}{2(\kappa + 2)}, \frac{1}{2(\kappa + 2)}\right\}.$$

What I have tried, taking individually the minimum value of $\alpha,$ put it into the main equation. But I don't find the exactly my desired expression.